# Angularjs watching for ng-class apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I'm using Angular `ui-router`. I have something like this:

```
<li ng-class="{ active: state.includes('panel') }">
```

I want to do something (ex. toggling the menu) **after** class was added. How can I know when exactly `active` class is applied to `li` tag?

**Note:** I used `$scope.$watch` , but it runs multiple times because of angular $digest cycle, and I use toggle for my menu, then at last, menu is closed!

Comment: state.include is function and it creates watch, so it runs multiple times because of angular $digest cycle

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: You can toggle the menu using the same conditions for setting the active state. `menu.isOpen = state.includes('panel')`

Comment: I dont think you can do it without using $watch, you can add check for `oldValue` and `newValue` - `function(newValue, oldValue){}` and apply change only if values are different

Comment: @Ladmerc I did that and watched for `menu.isOpen` , but on that point, class is not applied!

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle your menu using `ng-show` directive

```
<div class="panel" ng-show="state.includes('panel')">
</div>
```

This does not require setting any watches, since `ng-show` internally toggles the panel based on the value

Comment: Thanks. But it's not the way I go. Because `uikit` handles the menu toggle itself.